# SQL Server : how to work around WHERE IN limit of 128 values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (thousands of ids)
```

but this won't work because the limit of values for the `WHERE IN` is 128 on our version of SQL Server.

Is there a way to do this using a sub-query with a join, or maybe a temp table?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sure - insert all the Id's into a `#TEMP` or `@TABLE`, and then join to it on id?

Comment: Where are the thousands of ids coming from? Are they being generated from another query?

Comment: As far as I know, SQL Server has no such limit.  This might be imposed by some intervening software.  I'm pretty sure it is *not* 128, if there is a limit.

Comment: yes I was getting it from another query, so now I ended up just using a sub query and it seemed to work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`VALUES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) in order to construct an in-line table containing all the values to be considered and then `JOIN` to this table:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN (VALUES (10), (20), (12), ... ) AS t2(id) 
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Waowwwwwww never seen this before. Amazing approach

Comment: NIce plug but won't it be better if we use this in subquery  rather than join
coz logical tree are are not equivalent for join and subquery so after derived cardinality phase it may physically chooses  JOIN OVER SEMI JOIN. simple example below:

create table t (ID INT)


SELECT t1.*
FROM t AS t1
INNER JOIN (VALUES (10), (20), (12) ) AS t2(id) 
ON t1.id = t2.id


SELECT t1.*
FROM T AS t1

where
exists 
 (
 
 select * from
 (VALUES (10), (20), (12)) AS t2(id) 
 where t2.id =t1.id

 )

**see the execution plan**

Answer (score 3):

Place them in temp table and

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id from #Table_of_thousands_of_ids)
```

Comment: Good choice. Now someone please tell the EF and other ORM teams to also support this ;) But yes, this is the way to do it (or use a table valued variable, which may be a tad easier to work with in a query).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a temporary table, in which you will insert all your ids, then make a inner join with your table

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE
(
  Id int
)

Insert into @tmpTable (id) values (1), (2), (3)

SELECT *
FROM [table]
Inner join @tmpTable on [table].id = @tmpTable.id
```